# Docker Compose WordPress Volumes Appear Empty

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to set up a simple WordPress build using docker compose. However, when I build it, the volumes appear to be empty.

Here is my docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
    wordpress:
        image: wordpress
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 8000:80
        volumes:
            - ./development:/var/www/html
        environment:
            WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
            WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
            WORDPRESS_DB_USER: root
            WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: password
        depends_on:
            - db
        networks:
            - wordpress-network
    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
        ports:
            - 8080:80
        links:
            - db:db
    db:
        image: mariadb:latest
        ports:
            - 127.0.0.1:3306:3306
        command: [
            '--default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password',
            '--character-set-server=utf8mb4',
            '--collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
        ]
        volumes:
            - wp-data:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
        networks:
            - wordpress-network
networks:
    wordpress-network:
        driver: bridge

volumes:
    wp-data:
        driver: local
```

Here is my local project structure, with theme stylesheet:

[image]

I run docker-compose to build the image:
`docker-compose up -d --build`

But when I open the build in my browser, it looks like the theme is empty:

[image]

This leads me to believe the volume is empty. I'd appreciate any help or insights into this issue, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In your docker-compose file you say `./wp-data:/var/lib/mysql` which is host folder mapping (not volume) but in your docker-compose you define docker named volume called `wp-data` and if you want to use this volume you have to use it as `wp-data:/var/lib/mysql`. I would also suggest to remove `${PWD}` because it might cause problem in `sh`

Comment: Thanks, updating the "wp-data" volume helped with storage, but my issue is really with the themes volume and not appearing to copy the contents of the themes. I changed "${PWD}" to "./" and still am seeing the issue.

Comment: How do you run your docker compose?

Comment: `docker-compose up -d --build`

Comment: It might be issue that first you mount development and after that some subfolder from that folder, try to move it to different directory from top, or mount it just once

Comment: I removed the subfolder and am now just mounting the volume `./development:/var/www/html`, but still getting the same issue.

Comment: what if you go inside the container and `ls` in that folder is it also blank?

Comment: When I ssh onto the wordpress container using `docker-compose exec wordpress sh`, the "custom-theme" folder is there but empty.

Comment: i suggest you remove all your containers, delete volumes and start from scratch, i think your docker-compose is OK and it might be environment issue

Comment: I stopped all my instances and ran the command `docker system prune -a` to delete all containers & volumes. But running `docker-compose up -d --build` still results in the same issue.

Comment: i tested the wordpress docker-compose and it works OK, so it must be your enviroenmnt, update docker to latest version, stoping and `docker-compose down` is not the same, i dont understand why you use `--build` when you are not building anything, you could also try `--force-recreate` when you do `up`