# Docker-compose wordpress with costum theme + mysql

Tags: mysql, wordpress, docker, docker-compose

I need to do docker-compose: 1)wordpress with my theme 2) mysql.

How is this done in practice? And plus one condition, I will fold the .yam file to another person and it should launch in the same way, that is, there was a small problem, I can’t add a topic locally like COPY. / wp-content /

There is an idea to create your own wordpress image with the theme and connect it to docker-compose, but there were several unsuccessful attempts, please share a couple of examples of how to deploy wordpress with the customer’s site.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker Compose WordPress Volumes Appear Empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50191308/docker-compose-wordpress-volumes-appear-empty)

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this [Quickstart: Compose and WordPress](https://docs.docker.com/compose/wordpress/)?

Comment: There is no info about configuring volumes with `docker-compose`.